# Tag wikis: descriptive of questions or descriptive of topic?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

The [soteriology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soteriology) tag says ["Soteriology is the study of salvation as understood across different faiths"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/605).  Is it really "as understood across different faiths" or is soteriology just a catch-all word that can be used for each faith?

I mean, there's nothing ecumenical to soteriology, is there? It's just questions tagged with just soteriology are "denomination-agnostic" in and of themselves.

Personally, I'm as dense to the existence of the topic as I am to hermeneutics<sup>1</sup> and I don't really care one way or another, I just want to know if that's the correct definition of soteriology, because, not surprisingly, the [Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/14580a.htm) says nothing about soteriology being something "understood across different faiths".

---

Actually this post is more about what the purpose of tag wikis than the definition of soteriology (I just renamed the question, hopefully it still makes sense).  Should tag wikis be descriptive of the topic at hand (i.e. give an accurate description of what the tag is) or should tag wikis be descriptive of the questions asked with just the topic (i.e. not particular to one denomination)

<sup>1. at least that word shows up in my spell checker.</sup>

Comment: I had to add "hermeneutics" to mine. :P

Answer (score 8):

Descriptive of the types of questions that belong in that tag. Tag wikis while they can be descriptive of topic, are far more important about describing the types of questions that get tagged with that particular tag.

Comment: Currently a lot of tag wikis attempt to define the term. I've edited any of those that I find.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this was a general question you were asking, but I had to edit it.  It just stank too bad.